# Formula for a series that seems to be both geometric and arithmetic

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I haven't encountered one like this before..

I start with a value of 8 at t=0. Then at the end of a 4 hour period the amount at the beginning of the 4 hour period gets reduced by 70% and then an additional 8 is added.

The actual question is related to a drug for which 8mg of the drug is taken every 4 hours. Then the problem specifies that at the end of each 4 hour period 70% of the amount at the beginning of the 4 hour period remains in the body.  The question asks to find a series that represent the situation. Then also which does will we exceed 22mg in the body.

Comment: So what you need is the solution to the recurrence $x_{n+1} = 0.7 x_n + 8$ with $x_0 = 8$ (where $n$ is the number of 4-hour periods that have elapsed), if I'm interpreting you correctly?

Comment: Can't understand "Then at the **end** of a 4 hour period the amount at the **beginning** of **the** 4 hour period..."

Comment: You can rewrite the recursion as $$x_{n+1}-a=k(x_n-a)$$ if $a$ and $k$ are properly chosen.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ be equal to the value when $t=4n$. The recurrence relationship gives:

$$a_{n+1}=0.7*a_n+8$$

Evaluating this recursively for a given $n$ gives $0.7^n*a_0 + 0.7^{n-1}8 + 0.7^{n-2}8 ...$

This gives us a closed formula of:

$$a_n=(0.7)^n*a_0+8\frac{1-0.7^n}{1-0.7}$$

Comment: So is a0 the starting amount, ie 8? The actual question is related to a drug for which 8mg of the drug is taken every 4 hours. Then the problem specifies that at the end of each 4 hour period 70% of the amount at the beginning of the 4 hour period remains in the body.  We're asked to find a series that represent the situation.

Comment: Yes $a_0$ would be the value at $t=0$.

Comment: For $a_0 = 8$, the $a_n$ formula simplifies to $8(1-0.7^{n+1})/(1-0.7)$

Comment: Another approach to sequences like this is to let $b_n:=a_{n+1}-a_n$. Then $b_{n+1}=a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=0.7 (a_{n+1}-a_n)=0.7 b_n$, so $b_n$ is a geometric sequence.

Comment: Seeing your initial equation for recurrence, $a_{n+1}=0.7*a_n-8$ led me to answer as I thought you were on the wrong track, but after I posted, I see that it was just a typo ! Pl. correct it !

Comment: @McMath You should accept nice answers. I hope it is clear enough. Have a look to your other questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

After your clarification in a comment,

Let $q(0)$ = quantity of drug in body at time $0 = 8$, and measurements be every $4$ hours, then

$q(n+1) = 0.7*q(n) +8$

which recurrence relationship yields

$q(n) = (8/3)\left(10 - \frac{7^{n+1}}{10^n}\right)$

This may appear mysterious, but see the explanation below

---

*Explanation*

$\displaylines{q(0)= 8\\q(1) = 0.7*8 +8\\q(2) = 0.7^2*8 +0.7*8 +8\\q(3) = 0.7^3*8 + 0.7^2*8 +0.7*8 +8\;;  } and\; so\; on,$

We can write $q(3) = 8\left(1 +\frac7{10} +\left(\frac7{10}\right)^2 + \left(\frac7{10}\right)^3\right)$
which makes it clear that it is just  a G.P, now just apply the formula to get $q(n)$ and simplify.

You easily get $\Large q(n) = 8\times\frac{1-0.7^{n+1}}{0.3}$

I have just instead put it in a form avoiding decimals

Comment: Can you explain how you generated the q(n) formula? Also, how would you represent the series with a single formula? Thx

Comment: Your confusion was that it was both  a G.P. and an A.P. but, actually you can see that it is just a  G.P. written in reverse  with first term = 8, and common ratio = $0.7$ The "standard" way to write $q(n)$ would be $q(n) = 8\times\frac{1-0.7^{n+1}}{0.3}$ I have just given another form, avoiding decimals.